# Woocommerce: Custom field per product on the cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I'm building a website for a wholesale business that is selling plants. They want to provide their customers an option on the cart page to add labels to the plants. Therefore I want to add a custom input field per product in the cart where customers can type in the amount of plants they need. When the update cart button is clicked I want the amount of labels to be added to the cart item data.

I found that I can use `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_labels', 10, 3 );

function add_labels( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {

    $cart_item_data['amount_of_labels'] = 200;

    return $cart_item_data;

}
```

And when a product is added to the cart, a value of 200 is stored for the key 'amount_of_labels' in the product cart item data. This value is retrievable on the cart and checkout page and can be store in the order item meta data.

**My question is:**

Is there a same sort of hook/action available for updating cart data on the cart page itself?

I see that there is `woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update` hook. But it is not working properly for my case. With that hook I can't update my custom cart item data *(adding updating or removing)*.

**Example screenshot:**

Here you can see what I am trying to build. The inputs in the screenshot take the amount of labels and those should be added to the cart item data when updating the cart.

[image]

Comment: You should provide all related code in your question: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."*